# Is there any method to generate auto title inside wordpress post when publishing

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type where i can create post and publish.The title
can be any random string.
Is there any method to auto modify post title when a post is published?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set a title when a post is created on the back end, you have to use the `title_save_pre` filter. It works on creating a new post or updating an existing post without change.

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'modify_your_post_title' , '99', 1 ); 

function modify_your_post_title( $data )
{
  if($data['post_type'] == 'rating') { /

    $id = get_the_ID();
    $title = 'Post Title for ' . $id;
    $data['post_title'] =  $title ; //Updates the post title to your new title.
  }
  return $data; // Returns the modified data.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the accepted answer didn't work, as it took two saves to actually update the title with some values I pulled from ACF custom fields with `get_field()`.

What I had to do was to access the values trough `$postarr` instead, like it is recommended in the `wp_insert_post_data` docs:

```php
function modify_your_post_title( $data, $postarr, $unsanitized_postarr ) {

  if($data['post_type'] == 'your_post_type') { 
    $id = $postarr['ID'];
    $title = $postarr['acf']['field_65a95b23de2d4'] . ' - ' . $postarr['acf']['field_65a95bd0de2d5'];
    $data['post_title'] =  $title ; 
  }
  return $data; 
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'modify_your_post_title' , 99, 3 );
```